# How to loop/parse through table rows in order without skipping to next instance of a variable?

Tags: python, for-loop, html-table, scrapy, header

I'm new to all of this so please bear with me.  I have some knowledge of Java but I decided I wanted to learn to use scrapy and python recently.

As a project to help me get started I am trying to write a spider that will scrape online contact directories that I will then import to a csv.  For right now I am focusing on directories that are formatted as a .aspx table.

To this point I have gotten it working exactly how I want it with one exception being the headers.  In the directory, departments are separated by th tags containing the name of each department with everyone in that department listed below.

My goal is to set it up so the output is formatted like:
`[Department, Name, Title, Email, Phone#]`

However, with my current code, when a new row is parsed, the `xpath` I have set to find the header skips to the next instance of that `xpath`.

So assuming `Name1` and `Name2` are in `Department1` rather than the output for `Name2` looking like this:
`[Department1, Name2, Title, Email, Phone#]` 
the output looks like this because the selector for the Department header skipped to the next instance of that xpath.
`[Department2, Name2, Title, Email, Phone#]`
because it is the second contact entry and department is the second department entry.

Below is my parse.

It is set to loop through the table rows and for each row it will gather the contact information from the given xpath.

I tried writing an xpath contains statement to check if there was the header's xpath first but it didn't work and ultimately only printed the headers.

```
for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

  def parse(self, response):
      rows = response.xpath('//table/tbody/tr')
      for i in range(0, len(rows)-1):

          yield {
                  'header' : rows.xpath('//tr[@class="sidearm-staff-category "]/th//text()').extract()[i],
                  'col1' : rows.xpath('//th/a[1]//text()').extract()[i].strip(),
                  'col2' : rows.xpath('//td[1]//text()').extract()[i].strip(),
                  'col3' : rows.xpath('//td[2]/a//text()').extract()[i].strip(),
                  'col4' : rows.xpath('//td[3]/a//text()').extract()[i].strip(),
                  }
```

Here is my output (for the privacy of those in the directory I have replaced their email addresses and phone#s).

As you can see, where as the second entry's header should be the same as the first, instead it has gone on to the second department header.  How can I write an if statement or some sort of rule that will return the department header as the department variable for each staff member below it until it reaches a new department header.

```
{'header': 'Athletic Administration', 'col1': 'Laura  Courtley-Todd', 'col2': 'Director of Athletics', 'col3': 'email', 'col4': 'phone'}

2019-04-12 14:11:44 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://stubobcats.com/staff.aspx>
{'header': 'Athletic Communications', 'col1': 'Dr. Jan  Bell', 'col2': 'Faculty Athletics Representative', 'col3': 'email', 'col4': 'phone'}
```

Answer (score 1):

use beautiful soup and try a more pythonic way
learn about requests module
i dont think xpath should be used when the html is quote organized and elegant, ie: it's in organized tables
basically in bs4, select, find, find_all functions can get the job done
no regex necessary
in requests, learn about headers, user agent, referer header

```
pip install bs4
pip install requests

s=requests.Session()
u='www'
rp=s.get(u,headers=myheaders)
sp=soup(rp.text)
table=sp.find('table')
rows=table.select('tr')
for row in rows:
     print row.text
     a=row.select('a')
     print a['href']
```

Comment: Ok, I keep getting "myheaders is not defined".  Also how would I go about writing this into a spider?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using xpath selection you might be able to get away with using more specific selectors?:

```
cat1 = response.xpath('//*[@data-category-id="1"')
cat2 = response.xpath('//*[@data-category-id="2"')
```

And then use class selectors to pull the category types:

```
type1 = cat1.xpath('//*[@class="sidearm-staff-category"]'
type1_members = cat1.xpath('//*[@class="sidearm-staff-member"]'
type1_members.xpath('//td[@headers="col-fullname"]')
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I did a poor job of phrasing the question.  I think that's a good idea but my problem isn't so much with all of the columns as it is just the headers containing the department name. What I need is to set the parse to return the department header as the department variable for each staff member below it until it reaches a new department header.